# Devexpress LayoutControlGroup Header Size?

Tags: winforms, devexpress

I want to know if there is a way to resize a `LayoutGroupControl` header. I think the header is taking too much space in my form and I want to reduce this space. At this point I modify the `GroupBordersStyle`, but I want to keep the `ExpandButtonVisible` set to true.

Comment: Can you attach an image of how it should look?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Every problem with LayoutControl and its resizing is very difficult (I know, I develop with Devexpress).
Usual hack - subscribe to events Resize, SizeChanged and set Size of group manualy by

```
group.MaxSize = new Size(0, height);
```